# How to remove a small dot in enumerate?

Tags: enumerate

The code is

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\alph{enumi})}
\begin{enumerate}
\item The first item
\item The second item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There is a small dot behind `a) b)`. So how to remove it?

Comment: just add 
\renewcommand\labelenumi{\theenumi}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `enumitem` package to format lists:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\alph*)}]
\item The first item
\item The second item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

To make all `enumerate` lists look like this  (so you don't have to add the `label` specification to each one), you can add:

```
 \setlist[enumerate]{label=\alph*)}
```

which will make all `enumerate` lists look like this.  If you only want this format for a particular level of the list, you can add a level number to the optional argument:

```
 \setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\alph*)}
```

This will make only the first level have this format.

Answer (score 7):

Two more alternatives. One using basic principles and redefinitions from [`article.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\alph{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi)}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item The first item
  \item The second item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

...and using the older [`enumerate` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[a)]
  \item The first item
  \item The second item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```